# Is fork a git core concept?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Is forking a git repo possible through git core (command line, i.e.), or is it only a feature that github, bitbucket, etc., provide? I had similar question recently about pull-requests, but I discovered that pull-requests are not only feature provided by github, bitbucket, etc., but that is concept available in git core (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull). Is situation same with repo forking?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, fork is [clone](http://gitref.org/creating/#clone) in git core.